# Multiple storyboards in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have an app which has 4 storyboards, each for a different device (iphone4, 5, 6, 6+).  I have tried to use auto constraints but since my app is complicated, I wasn't able to figure it out.   I have heard that if you have multiple storyboards there should be a way of specifying which storyboard to use in the app delegate.  How do I go about specifying the proper storyboard for the proper device in the app delegate?  I currently have four storyboards, named:

iphone4s.storyboard 
iphone5.storyboard 
iphone6.storyboard 
iphone6plus.storyboard

Thank you.

Comment: why you use 4 storyboards, in single storyboard handle the all devices bro, plz optimize the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a function that retrieves the storyboard when it's name is specified.

```
func getStoryBoard(name : String)-> UIStoryboard
{
    var storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: name, bundle: nil);
    return storyBoard;
}
```

Change the app delegate method like:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    var storyBoard = getStoryBoard("Main") // Change the storyboard name based on the device, you may need to write a condition here for that
    var initialViewController: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Comment: Even though this answer was buried at the bottom of the thread, it was the only one that worked.  Sorry it took so long to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

According to me these days we make use of **autoLayout** which knows how to layout its view for depending on screen size and constraints

As you asked you can override the storyboard from AppDelegate in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iphone4s", bundle: nil)
    //you can check your device and override the storyboard name
    let initialViewController: UIViewController =  storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    self.window?.rootViewController? = initialViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to launch different storyboards for various device, you need to override rootViewController Object.

```
       var myDeviceStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DeviceStoryboard", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

        var firstVC : MyDeviceFirstViewController = myDeviceStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyDeviceFirstViewController") as! MyDeviceFirstViewController


        self.window?.rootViewController = MyDeviceFirstViewController //This should be a navigation controller
```

Also, you need to override few settings in Project settings, and Storyboard. Refer images attached.[image]